# select two grouped by columns but only select row with the highest COUNT()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that consists of three columns - UPC, ATTRIBUTE, STORE_NUM. I have 10 stores and 2 UPCs at each with different ATTRIBUTEs.

Every store either has either attribute X or Y. I group by UPC and ATTRIBUTE and get the count of stores.

```
SELECT [UPC], [ATTRIBUTE], COUNT([STORE_NUM]) AS [COUNT]
FROM TABLEA
GROUP BY [UPC], [ATTRIBUTE]
```

Yields this:

```
UPC    ATTRIBUTE   COUNT
1      X           8
1      Y           2
2      X           1
2      Y           9
```

And I want to select UPC and ATTRIBUTE with the highest count. My desired output would be this:

```
UPC      ATTRIBUTE
1        X
2        Y
```

I can't figure out how to reach this desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions with aggregation:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [UPC], [ATTRIBUTE], COUNT(*) AS [COUNT],
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UPC ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM TABLEA
      GROUP BY [UPC], [ATTRIBUTE]
     ) x
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Use `RANK()` if you want duplicates in the event of ties.

Answer (score 1):

Use row_number and a subquery:

```
SELECT UPC, ATTRIBUTE
FROM (
      SELECT  UPC, ATTRIBUTE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UPC ORDER BY a_count DESC) as rn
      FROM ( SELECT [UPC],[ATTRIBUTE],COUNT([STORE_NUM]) AS [a_COUNT]
             FROM TABLEA
             GROUP BY [UPC],[ATTRIBUTE]
           ) t
     ) q
WHERE q.rn = 1
```